# Why does Show these items link bring up a blank page?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, document-library, permissions

I click on a document library, select library tab - library settings - permissions for this document library, Show these items, working on it... appears and the window is blank.  See attachments.[image: Show these items]

[image: Blank Window]

How do I resolve this?

Comment: please add details about your SharePoint environment. is is SharePoint Online !  have you done any customization !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally speaking, this situation will not occur. **We recommend that you perform the following troubleshootings：**

1. Switch to other Document libraries or Sites to see if similar situations occur.
2. Have you made some custom settings, such as powershell commands
3. Clear the browser cache,

4.Use another browser, such as IE, Edge, Chrome.

- **PS:** Your environment is the SharePoint Online or SharePoint Server 2010/2013/2016/2019?

There is a same post in the Q&A forum:

- **[Why does Show these items link bring up a blank page?](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/405090/why-does-show-these-items-link-bring-up-a-blank-pa.html?childToView=406566#answer-406566)**

Comment: 1.  I duplicated in other libraries.
 2. No custom settings.
 3. Cleared browser cache
 4. Duplicated in IE, Chrome and Firefox
 5. SharePoint 2013


I found that the window finally loaded after 3-5 minutes.

Comment: Hi, C1TonyB. Thanks for your reply. This may be due to the network either because the page is in the process of loading caused.